# css text vertical alignment changes from textarea element to input element

Tags: html, css

I'm not good in css and not able to quick fix this issue.

I have the following html, css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>temp</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Studio 3 http://aptana.com/">
        <meta name="author" content="Subhranath Chunder">
        <!-- Date: 2011-08-19 -->
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                width:400px;
            }
            p, input {
                display:inline-block;
                height:80px;
            }
            ul.error-list, li {
                display:inline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p><input type="text" value="Name" name="name" /></p><ul class="error-list"><li>Error 1</li></ul>
            <p><input type="text" value="Email" name="email" /></p><ul class="error-list"><li>Error 1</li></ul>
            <p><textarea name="address" />Address</textarea></p><ul class="error-list"><li>Error 1</li></ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The first two error messages corresponding to the first two input elements is getting vertically centered. But, for the textarea element, the error message is vertically at the bottom.

If I change the last element to input type element, then it gets vertically centered. But, I need the last element to be of textarea type.

Can anyone fix the css, and give an explanation of why it's behaving as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            width:400px;
        }
        p, input, textarea {
            display:inline-block;
            height:80px;
        }
        ul.error-list, li {
            display:inline;
        }
        textarea {
            vertical-align:middle;
        }
    </style>
```

As for why this happens: `input` and `textarea` are different elements, and they behave in different ways. Possibly because `input` only takes one line of text, and the error message is by default aligned to the bottom line of text, for inputs it looks as you want it to. But `textarea` takes many lines of text, so the error message aligns to the bottom of the element, rather than the bottom of the text in the element.